# Scala parameterized type problem with returning an instance of the same type

Tags: generics, scala, scala-2.8

In the following, I will present only very reduced versions of my Scala code. Just enough to show the problem. Unnecessary blocks of code will be reduced to `...`.

### The part that works

I have created a vector library (that is, for modeling mathematical vectors, not vectors in the sense of `scala.collection.Vector`). The basic trait looks like this:

```
trait Vec[C] extends Product {
  def -(o:Vec[C]):Vec[C] = ...
  ...
}
```

I have created numerous subtypes for specific vectors, like `Vec2` for two-dimensional vectors, or `Vec2Int` specialized for two-dimensional `Int` vectors.

The subtypes narrow the return types of some operations. For example, subtracting a `Vec2Int` from another vector will not return a generic `Vec[Int]`, but the more specific `Vec2Int`.

Additionally, I have declared those methods in very specific subtypes like `Vec2Int` as `final`, thereby allowing the compiler to elect those methods for inlining.

This works very well, and I have created a fast and usable library for vector calculations.

Building on top of that, I now want to create a set of types to model basic geometrical shapes. The basic shape trait looks like this:

```
trait Shape[C, V <: Vec[C]] extends (V=>Boolean) {
  def boundingBox:Box[C,V]
}
```

Where `Box` would be a subtype of `Shape`, modeling an n-dimensional box.

### The part that does not work

Now, I tried to define box:

```
trait Box[C, V <: Vec[C]] extends Shape[C,V] {
  def lowCorner:V
  def highCorner:V
  def boundingBox = this
  def diagonal:V = highCorner - lowCorner // does not compile
}
```

The `diagonal` method does not compile, because the method `Vec.-` returns `Vec[C]`, not `V`.

Of course, I could make `diagonal` return a `Vec[C]`, but this would be unacceptable in many ways. For once, I would lose the compiler optimization for specific `Vec` subtypes. Also, When you for example have a box described by two two-dimensional `Float` vectors (`Vec2Float`), it makes a lot of sense to assume that the diagonal is also a `Vec2Float`. I do not want to lose that information.

### My attempt to fix the problem

Following the example of the Scala collection hierarchy, I introduced a type `VecLike`:

```
trait VecLike[C, +This <: VecLike[C,This] with Vec[C]] {
  def -(o:Vec[C]):This
  ...
}
```

and I made `Vec` extend it:

```
trait Vec[C] extends Product with VecLike[C, Vec[C]] ...
```

(I would then go on to create more specific subtypes of `VecLike`, like `Vec2Like` or `Vec3Like`, to accompany my hierarchy of `Vec` types.)

Now, the new definition for `Shape` and `Box` looks like this:

```
trait Shape[C, V <: VecLike[C,V] with Vec[C]] ...

trait Box[C, V <: VecLike[C,V] with Vec[C]] extends Shape[C,V] {
  ...
  def diagonal:V = highCorner - lowCorner 
}
```

Still, the compiler complains:

```
Error: type mismatch;
found: Vec[C]
required: V
```

This confuses me. The type `VecLike` clearly returns `This` in the minus method, which translates to the type parameter `V` of the `Box` type. I can see that the minus method of `Vec` still returns `Vec[C]`, but why cannot the compiler at this point use the return type of `VecLike`'s minus method?

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Just a word of advice--I tried doing this a while ago and ran into some of the same problems, plus problems with specialization.  I found that it ended up being considerably easier to write a code generator to make a small vector/matrix library.

Comment: @Rex Kerr: Thanks for the advice. This is my second try. In the first try, I ended up with too many specific classes, and unmanageable code. This time, I limited specialization to 1, 2 and 3 dimensions and five numerical types. Should I need more in the future or find the code base unmanageable, I definitely will use a code generator. Which one did you use? Any recommendations?

Comment: I wrote my own code generator in Scala, and have dimensions 2-4 for vectors and square matrices, and the five most useful primitive types (Short, Int, Long, Float, Double). (Actually, the generator can generate arbitrary dimensions, but the size of the generated library starts getting unwieldy past 4.) The generator's only about 1k lines of code, and it does things that I was never able to figure out how to do correctly with specialization (e.g. conversions between types and promotion of Long+Float to Double). I wish you the best of luck! It _is_ nicer to work with code than a code generator.

Comment: @Rex Kerr: Thanks a lot for those comments. It is amazing how similar our ideas are - I specialized for exactly the same primitive types as you did, and I have also consider writing a code generator in Scala. So far, I did not do it because I have too much respect before such a task. But it's great to see how you did exactly that and ended up successfully with a useful library.

Comment: @Madoc - Incidentally, if you want to see what I did, I uploaded an alpha version a while ago to http://code.google.com/p/shipvl/

Comment: @Rex Kerr: Thanks! There is a lot I can learn from your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My advice is to work much less hard on omitting the code you think is irrelevant, and just show the code.  It's really amazing how often people manage to remove the part which matters.  The mantra is "if you don't know why it doesn't work, then you don't know what is relevant." This is very serious, genuine advice: I can help you in five seconds if you give me code which would compile except for the thing you don't understand, or I can help you in five minutes if I have to reconstruct all the pieces you left out.  Guess which one happens more often.

On to the code.  It compiles exactly as given, after I make guesses about how the bits from the first attempt fill into the second attempt.  (This "guessing" phase is another good reason to show the code up front.)

```
trait VecLike[C, +This <: VecLike[C, This] with Vec[C]] {
  def -(o: Vec[C]): This
}

trait Vec[C] extends Product with VecLike[C, Vec[C]] { }

trait Shape[C, V <: VecLike[C,V] with Vec[C]] { }

trait Box[C, V <: VecLike[C,V] with Vec[C]] extends Shape[C, V] {
  def lowCorner: V
  def highCorner: V
  def boundingBox = this
  def diagonal: V = highCorner - lowCorner 
}

% scalac281 a.scala 
%
```

Comment: Since my `Vec` type with its companion alone has 121 lines of code, I chose to shorten it. When you add the minus method in your code example to `Vec`, as in the first code block of my question, then the code won't compile any more. (`def -(o:Vec[C]):Vec[C] = ...`) Omitting the return type of the minus method does not help either. The only option that works is to remove the definition of the minus method from `Vec` completely. Although I still don't understand exactly why, this helps me. I will pull the default implementations for `VecLike` methods out of `Vec`. Thanks!

Comment: The definition of - you just described declares itself to return Vec[C].  The declaration of diagonal declares itself to return V, which is some subtype of Vec[C].  Supplying an AnyRef doesn't mean you get a String, even if the AnyRef happens to be a String.  You need the return type of the method to move in unison with V -- that is what "This" achieves in VecLike, and why it works there and not in Vec.

Comment: @extempore: `-` is defined and inherited twice; once in `Vec` and once in `VecLike`. While the `Vec` definition returns `Vec`, the `VecLike` definition returns `This`. So it seems to me like the Scala compiler could have a choice as to which one it follows in `diagonal`. If it would follow the one from `VecLike`, then there would be no problem at all. So why does it choose to follow the one from `Vec`? And how could I implement `-` in `Vec` to return `This`? There is no `This` type parameter variable in `Vec`...

Comment: @Madoc - If you follow the example of the Scala collections, XLike does almost everything while X itself does almost nothing.  So the question is: why have `-` in `Vec` at all, if `VecLike` has it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean about a choice.  In your code you are making a claim that is not true: the method doesn't return V.  Nobody has any choice in this matter.  If the - method is defined twice (this is another detail which you did not make at all clear) then the implementation must satisfy both: it must be "This" and "V".  Since it isn't V, you're no closer.

Comment: @Rex Kerr: My default implementations of the arithmetic methods use an object that is internally provided by `Vec`. But I think I'll get around it.